# Could not resolve host gitlab ci/cd

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

Gitlab is deployed in scaleway instance and Gitlab runner is installed on ubuntu instance in scaleway.
And can not resolve repository URL

Here is the output of the job

Running with gitlab-runner 14.5.1 (de104fcd) on Docker runner eeN3xtPo Preparing the "docker" executor Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-build-image/master:stable ... Starting service docker:stable-dind ... Pulling docker image docker:stable-dind ... Using docker image sha256:6f19136cf89d49aee8fa560eaab20e034c6ee17bbce55a9d33e1fbe5baa35b03 for docker:stable-dind with digest docker@sha256:4972457c6a8a4309f9796fc3c8fd288923045ba0e214c102d92b70be99e249d1 ... Waiting for services to be up and running...
*** WARNING: Service runner-een3xtpo-project-16-concurrent-0-2cdd61dc4972b45e-docker-0 probably didn’t start properly.

Health check error:
service “runner-een3xtpo-project-16-concurrent-0-2cdd61dc4972b45e-docker-0-wait-for-service” timeout

Health check container logs:

Service container logs:
2021-12-06T08:12:32.256105257Z Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
2021-12-06T08:12:33.779949217Z …++++
2021-12-06T08:12:34.035263835Z …++++
2021-12-06T08:12:34.036190338Z e is 65537 (0x010001)
2021-12-06T08:12:34.069658359Z Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
2021-12-06T08:12:34.192151526Z …++++
2021-12-06T08:12:36.084178115Z …++++
2021-12-06T08:12:36.085150434Z e is 65537 (0x010001)
2021-12-06T08:12:36.145062798Z Signature ok
2021-12-06T08:12:36.145105028Z subject=CN = docker:dind server
2021-12-06T08:12:36.146660863Z Getting CA Private Key
2021-12-06T08:12:36.167473745Z /certs/server/cert.pem: OK
2021-12-06T08:12:36.178713113Z Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
2021-12-06T08:12:37.471672177Z …++++
2021-12-06T08:12:37.613945973Z …++++
2021-12-06T08:12:37.614534882Z e is 65537 (0x010001)
2021-12-06T08:12:37.668334299Z Signature ok
2021-12-06T08:12:37.668378742Z subject=CN = docker:dind client
2021-12-06T08:12:37.668696700Z Getting CA Private Key
2021-12-06T08:12:37.694020835Z /certs/client/cert.pem: OK
2021-12-06T08:12:37.711885583Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
2021-12-06T08:12:37.714604837Z Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
2021-12-06T08:12:37.714654611Z AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
2021-12-06T08:12:37.716337204Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)

Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-build-image/master:stable …
Using docker image sha256:c34686777225a2963abd71cd554fe1d68739cd9f34e281e9f49b2747053877b7 for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-build-image/master:stable with digest registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-build-image/master@sha256:d4fb8a36f67a3bdbe0b208b037ef5fbb61205b019a35dba14063b540ec0f34f8 …
Preparing environment
Running on runner-een3xtpo-project-16-concurrent-0 via 7f9f41842641…
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes…
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/Nedislav/testcicd/.git/
Created fresh repository.
fatal: unable to access ‘http://4fdbbd17-693b-45c1-bb2e-07b18837958a.pub.cloud.scaleway.com/Nedislav/testcicd.git/’: Could not resolve host: 4fdbbd17-693b-45c1-bb2e-07b18837958a.pub.cloud.scaleway.com
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: You have a network error somewhere in your deployment. Likely candidates would be your security group around your instance, however the DNS you posted doesn't resolve publicly so that may be an issue as well.

Comment: Thank you I will check the security group. The DNS does not resolved because I have powered off the instance.

Comment: Update I made new security group and allowed TCP, UDP and ICMP between the two instances, but the result is the same.

Comment: Assuming your instance is still up since you posted 10s ago, I still can't resolve the DNS for your instance, which would match the error your runner is reporting. Are you sure that DNS record is valid? Can you try to have the runner connect via IP instead to remove that from the potential problem pool?

Comment: I am turning off the instances when I stop working, sorry for that. I connect the runner via the IP address.

Comment: Public DNS
4fdbbd17-693b-45c1-bb2e-07b18837958a.pub.instances.scw.cloud
Private DNS
4fdbbd17-693b-45c1-bb2e-07b18837958a.priv.instances.scw.cloud

Comment: Here are the two dns of  the instance the other strange thing is that when I am in may repository and click clone. http://4fdbbd17-693b-45c1-bb2e-07b18837958a.pub.cloud.scaleway.com/Nedislav/testcicd.git it is not using the IP here too. I tried to change it in advance setting but there is using the IP and it is now allowed to be changed.

Comment: I edited the config.toml file and added extra_hosts and clone-url and it is working now. Thank you for your assistance!!